# mysql -uroot fails / succeeds randomly

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I have installed mysql with homebrew two weeks ago and everything works fine until today.

I have tried to connect to mysql with the classic command `mysql -uroot` and the behaviour following this command is **really** random. Sometimes, I'll connect successfully and sometimes I'll get the following error message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I say random, I mean that whenever it fails, I relaunch the command several times (~5 times) before it works.

Yet, I have no idea why:

- the success of the operation is so random
- what could have ignited such a behaviour (i.e why I am facing this issue only now)

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't  think you did enough research regarding this error relating to homebrew since there's so many resources/solutions available regarding this error.

You can try to run `brew services restart mysql` or `brew services start mysql` and also take a look at the [homebrew-services page](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services)